# Cloudant-Python document retrieval

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, paging

I have a large db in Cloudant and I want to retrieve all the docs using Python, the issue is the size of the db, therefore I want to use paging while retrieving the docs.

Comment: What did you try? What's the issue you're having? Please don't just ask us to provide a program according to your specification.

Answer (score 0):

You could incrementally fetch batches of documents from the Cloudant/CouchDB database by specifying the `limit` and `skip` [parameters](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/using_views.html#using-views).

Simple example that fetches 10 documents starting with the 21st:

```
GET .../_all_docs?limit=10&skip=20 HTTP/1.1

{
 "total_rows": 1...3,
 "offset": 20,
 "rows": [
  {
    "id": "0001ba...db5f6affa44631af9053",
    "key": "0001b...db5f6affa44631af9053",
    "value": {
      "rev": "1-d1fd2c...e52f2f28539e443c88"
    }
  },
  ...
 ]
}
```

This approach works for all views.